# Javascript countdown settimeout

Tags: javascript, refactoring, settimeout

im trying to make a simple javascript countdown timer which changes the value from 3 to 1 in the button every one second interval. I got the code working but it uses many functions. I was wondering if i could make it using less. ive tried to put the countdown in a for loop which displays the i value but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Heres my code:

```
 function launch( )
{
  document.getElementById("blast").value = "Preparing to launch...";
  setTimeout ( "countdown3()", 1000 );
}
function countdown3()
{
    document.getElementById("blast").value = "3";
    setTimeout("countdown2()", 1000);
}
function countdown2()
{
    document.getElementById("blast").value = "2";
    setTimeout("countdown1()", 1000);
}

function countdown1()
{
document.getElementById("blast").value = "1";
setTimeout("GO()", 1000 );
}
function GO()
{
    document.getElementById("blast").value = "BLAST OFF";
    move();
}
```

Comment: Please do not pass a string to `setTimeout`; use a function instead: `setTimeout(countdown3, 1000);` or if you need to pass some arguments `setTimeout(function() { whatever('foo'); }, 1000);` - passing a string is as bad as using `eval`!

Comment: At first i didnt pass them as a string but it didnt work until i did

Comment: You probably used `setTimeout(countdown(), ...)` which indeed doesn't work. That passes the return value of the function which is not a function anymore in your case.

Answer (score 3):

How about this :

```
function launch(seconds, id, message, callback)
{
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    target.innerHTML = message;

    var countDownId = setInterval( function(){
       target.innerHTML = seconds;
       if(seconds == 0){
          clearInterval(countDownId);
          callback(target);          
       }
       seconds--;
    }, 1000 );

}

function GO(target)
{
    target.innerHTML = "BLAST OFF";
    move();
}

launch(3, "blast", "Preparing to launch...", GO);
```

Comment: +1 Tested and works!  Repeats the move function over and over again.

Comment: @jmort253, what do you mean over and over again ? it should really only call move once.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function launch( )
{
    var countdown = function (index) {
        if(index > 0) {
          document.getElementById("blast").value = index;
          setTimeout (function() { countdown(index - 1) }, 1000 );
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("blast").value = "BLAST OFF";
          move();
        }  
    };

    document.getElementById("blast").value = "Preparing to launch...";
    setTimeout (function() { countdown(3) }, 1000 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
var i = 4;
document.getElementById("blast").value = 'Preparing to launch...';
function doIt(){
  var timerId = setInterval(function(){
    i--;
    if( i > 0 )
       document.getElementById("blast").value = i;
    else {
       document.getElementById("blast").value = 'BLAST OFF'; 
       clearInterval(timerId);
    }
  },1000);
}
```

Comment: This just outputs "blast". I never saw any counters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way that works with any messages, not just a countdown. Obviously it's not a good thing if you have longer countdowns - but with your current message-to-counter ratio I'd say it's a good solution:

```
function launch() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('blast');
    var step = 0;
    var messages = ['Preparing to launch', '3', '2', '1', 'LIFTOFF'];
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        elem.value = messages[step++];
        if(step < messages.length) {
            window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        }
    }, 1);
}

launch();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/qmBXs/

Comment: I think my way is much more generic, also , arguments.callee is deprecated in ECMAScript 5

Comment: Yeah, your solution is even nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using recursion, something like:

```
var blast = document.getElementById("blast");
countdown();

function countdown() {
 var nwvalue = Number(blast.value)-1; 
 blast.value = nwvalue;
 if (nwvalue>0) {
  setTimeout(countdown, 1000 ); //- value>0: call countdown in a timeout again
 } else {
  blast.value = 'all done';     //- here you would call GO()
 }
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/pa7bV/)

Answer (score 1):

This works (tested on chrome)

```
function launch( )
{
  document.getElementById("blast").value = "Preparing to launch...";
  setTimeout ( "countdown(3)", 1000 );
}

function countdown(index)
{
    if(index==0) {
         GO();
         return
    }

    document.getElementById("blast").value = index;
    setTimeout("countdown("+(--index)+")", 1000);
}

function GO()
{
    document.getElementById("blast").value = "BLAST OFF";
    move();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i =3;
function launch( )
{
  document.getElementById("blast").value = "Preparing to launch...";
  setTimeout ( function() { countDown() }, 1000 );
}
function countDown()
{
if(i<0)
   i="blast off";
document.getElementById("blast").value = i;
i--;
setTimeout("countDown()",1000);

}
```

try this

Comment: Please change "countDown()" to `function() { countDown() }` as it's not advisable to put strings where a function should go.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for me when i try to pass it as a function. Using chrome btw

Comment: It has to be an anonymous function that invokes the countDown, like so:  `setTimeout(function() { countDown(); }, 1000);` This is compatible with all the major browsers, including the IE family.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this solution in the Chrome Debugger tools. Replace the document.getElementById properties with console.info and run it in the debugger to see the output on the console.

```
function countdown(start, duration) {

    if(start == duration) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("blast").value = "BLAST OFF";
            // console.info("BLAST OFF");
        },duration * 1000);
        return;
    } else {

        setTimeout(function() {

            document.getElementById("blast").value = start;
            // console.info(start);

        }, (duration-start) * 1000);
        countdown(start+1, duration);
    }    

}

countdown(0,3);  // 3 seconds
```